# jQuery: Finding link best matching to current URL

Tags: jquery, url-routing

I have the following code which tries to add a class of selected to a link that matches the url:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li a').each(function()
    {
        if (pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) == 0)
        {
            $(this).parents('li').addClass('selected');
        }
    });
});
```

1.) So for example if I have a url like `/Organisations/Journal` and `/Organisations/Journal/Edit` a link with Organisations and Journal will show as being selected. This is fine!

2.) However sometimes I have urls like: `/Organisations` and `/Organisations/Archived` and if I have a link to the Archived then both will be selected **BUT** I don't want this to happen because the Organisations like doesn't have the second part of the url so shouldn't match.

Can anyone help with getting this working for the second types **Without** breaking the first type? Also none of this can be hardcoded regex looking for keywords as the urls have lots of different parameters!

Cheers

EXAMPLES:

If the url is `/Organisations/` Or `/Organisations` then a link with `/Organisations` should be selected. If the URL is `/Organisations/Journal/New` then a link with `/Organisations/Journal` or `/Organisations/Journal/New` would be selected.

BUT if I have a url with `/Organisations/Recent` and have two links: `/Organisations` and `/Organisations/Recent` then only the second should be selected! So the thing to note here is that it must have a third parameter before it should look for bits of the URL more loosly rather than an exact match.

Remember it might not always be Organisations so it can't be hardcoded into the JS!

Comment: Can you elaborate on your examples a bit more? Perhaps even provide a jsFiddle with the two cases?

Comment: Okay, am I getting this right … You want the *best match* to be highlighted as current?

Comment: Yes that's correct but as shown in the examples only one link would ever be highlighted so essentially if their is a better match highlight that over another one that might have been close.

Comment: Their is a time limit before I can accept an answer and I don't always have time to check back when it has expired and sometimes I don't always get the answer I want! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** My previous solution was quite over-complicated. Updated answer and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt2zR/4/).

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var best_distance = 999; // var to hold best distance so far
    var best_match = false;  // var to hold best match object

    $('ul#ui-ajax-tabs li a').each(function()
    {
        if (pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) == 0)
        {
            // we know that the link is part of our path name.
            // the next line calculates how many characters the path name is longer than our link
            overlap_penalty = pathname.replace($(this).attr('href'), '').length;
            if (overlap_penalty < best_distance) { // if we found a link that has less difference in length that all previous ones ...
                best_distance = overlap_penalty; // remember the length difference
                best_match = this; // remember the link
            }
        }
    });

    if (best_match !== false)
    {
        $(best_match).closest('li').addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

The best match is calculated like so:

Assume our pathname is "/foo/bar/baz/x".
We have two links in question:

- /foo/bar/
- /foo/bar/baz

This is what happens:

1. <strike>/foo/bar/</strike>baz/x (the first link's url is deleted from the path name `pathname.replace($(this).attr('href'), '')`)
2. "baz/x" is what remains.
3. The character count (`length`) of this remainder is 5. this is our "penalty" for the link.
4. We compare 5 to our previous best distance (`if (overlap_penalty < best_distance)`). 5 is lower (=better) than 999.
5. We save `this` (being the `<a href="/foo/bar/">` DOM object) for possible later use.
6. The second link is handled in the same manner:
7. <strike>/foo/bar/baz</strike>/x (the second link's url is deleted from the path name)
8. "/x" is what remains.
9. The character count of this remainder is 2.
10. We compare 2 to our previous best distance (being 5). 2 is lower than 5.
11. We save `this` (being the `<a href="/foo/bar/baz">` DOM object) for possible later use.

In the end, we just check if we found any matching link and, if so, apply `addClass('selected')` to its closest `<li>` parent.

Comment: Holy Cow that's some complicated code :P Although seems to be doing the job. Any chance you could explain what it's doing at each line though? Would like to learn more. Cheers.

Comment: Updated the answer. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u use

```
if($(this).attr('href') == pathname )
```

instead of

```
if (pathname.indexOf($(this).attr('href')) == 0)
```

Comment: Because that will look for **exact** matches!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var windowLocationPathname = "/HTMLPage14.htm";  // For testing purpose.

            //Or

            //var windowLocationPathname = window.location.pathname;

            $('ul.ui-ajax-tab').find('a[href^="' + windowLocationPathname + '"]').addClass('currentPage');
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .ui-ajax-tab
        {
            list-style: none;
        }

        a.currentPage
        {
            color: Red;
            background-color: Yellow;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="ui-ajax-tab">
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage14.htm">Test 1 (/HTMLPage14.htm)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage15.htm">Test 2 (/HTMLPage15.htm)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage16.htm">Test 3 (/HTMLPage16.htm)</a></li>
        <li><a href="/HTMLPage17.htm">Test 4 (/HTMLPage17.htm)</a></li>        
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would match EXACT matches... Which isn't what I wanted.